# Filter array by property and other array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter

I have a planning, with multiple items.
My object is like this :

```
planning: [
  { id: '1', equipe: [ '1', '2' ] },
  { id: '2', equipe: [ '1' ] },
  { id: '3', equipe: [ '2', '3' ] }
  ...
]
```

I want to filter this array to hide or show planning items.
My shown array is :

```
checked: [ '1', '4' ]
```

So, the array planning could be filtered by equipe array, so it should be :

```
planning: [
  { id: '1', equipe: [ '1', '2' ] },
  { id: '2', equipe: [ '1' ] }
]
```

I've tried to filter array but I don't see how indexOf could work with array and not string.
I've also tried includes function but this doens't work:

```
planning.filter(item => checked.includes(item.equipe))
```

Thask for help !

Comment: `planning.filter(item => checked.includes(item.equipe))` In this you are not checking if any element from checked array is present within the equipe instead you are checking whether checked contains the equipe array itself.

Comment: So what I have to do ?

Comment: Added my implementation below as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need iterate over each value from `item.equipe` against `checked`, you could use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one matches `checked` array:

```
planning.filter(item => item.equipe.some(val => checked.includes(val)))
```

```js
const planning = [
  { id: '1', equipe: [ '1', '2' ] },
  { id: '2', equipe: [ '1' ] },
  { id: '3', equipe: [ '2', '3'] }
]
   
const checked = [ '1', '4' ]
   
const filtered = planning.filter(item => item.equipe.some(val => checked.includes(val)))
   
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the logic in this manner.

```js
//Original Data
let planning = [
    { id: '1', equipe: ['1', '2'] },
    { id: '2', equipe: ['1'] },
    { id: '3', equipe: ['2', '3'] }
]

/**
 * Converting checked into Set so it will maintain all the unique values.
 * I can check which elements are present in O(1) using checked.has(value)
 */
let checked = new Set(['1', '4'])


/**
 * Using standard filter() function. 
 * Using some() to check if atleast 1 element from equipe is present in Set. 
 * If yes then checked.has(element) evaluates to true and some() receives atleast 1 element is valid and the element passes the filter.
 */

let filtered = planning.filter(plan => {
    return plan.equipe.some(element => checked.has(element));
})

console.log(filtered)
```